# Restricting the generating set of a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Given a collection of sets $I$, define

$$ I|_A := \{B \in I | B \subseteq A\}.$$

It is then the case that $\sigma(J)|_A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra for any collection $J$ containing $A$.

My question is: does $\sigma(J|_A) = \sigma(J)|_A$ when $A \subseteq J$? That the left-hand side is a subset of the right is straightforward, but I am having trouble showing the reverse inclusion.

Comment: When one has trouble proving something, it is often a good idea to start trying to disprove it. If one succeeds disproving it, the matter is settled. Otherwise, the way in which one fails to disprove may help finding a proof.

Answer (score 0):

We suppose that if $F$ is a class of subsets of the base space $\Omega$, then under $\sigma(F)$ we understand a minimal $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of the space $\Omega$ generated by the class $F$.

Then,  the  equality $\sigma(J|_A) = \sigma(J)|_A$, in general,  is not valid.

Indeed, let $A=\{1\},$ $J=\{ \{1,2\},\{1,2,3\}\}$. $\Omega=\{1,2,3\}$. Then

$J|_A=\emptyset$. Hence $\sigma(J|_A)=\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$.

$\sigma(J)=\{ \{1,2\},\{3\},\emptyset, \Omega\}$.

Hence $\sigma(J)|_A=\{ \emptyset \}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am interested in the specific case where $A \subseteq J$. I have amended my question to make this more explicit.